# Dynamically call functions depending on name

Tags: javascript

So I have a prototype object which registers an event listener. The listener receives an object and a string indicating the source of the emitted event.
The object will be the argument of some function calls (`_convertToX(someObj)`, `_convertToY(someObj)`, ...).
Now what I am trying to do is **dynamically** call my `convert` functions (as there might be some more added in the future), each of them takes exactly one argument (`someObj`).

```
// constructor
const MyFactory = function () {
    // ...

    $rootScope.$on('someObj:changed', (event, someObj, source) => {
        // TODO: call converters dynamically, but not the one which converts back to the source
        // source can be 'X', 'Y' or 'Z'
    });
}

MyFactory.prototype._convertToX = function (someObj) {
    // TODO: convert to X and emit
};

MyFactory.prototype._convertToY = function (someObj) {
    // TODO: convert to Y and emit
};

MyFactory.prototype._convertToZ = function (someObj) {
    // TODO: convert to Z and emit
};
```

*There already might be answers to similar questions on SO but I didn't know how to find the right search terms...*

My approach would be to create an array with all the `converter` function and call them in from the array. The issue I see is how can I make sure I don't call the converter which converts back to `source`?

```
/**
 * Hold references to all converters.
 * @type {Array<function>}
 */
this._converters = [
    this._convertToX,
    this._convertToY,
    this._convertToZ
];

// assume source is 'Z'
$rootScope.$on('someObj:changed', (event, someObj, source) => {
    // how to call each function in this._converters with someObj as argument
    // except this._convertToZ(someObj) ?
});
```

Is this a clean approach? How to do this?
Or is there a cleaner / simpler way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the function based on *string literal*

```
const MyFactory = function () {
    //Store the reference to a variable
    const self = this;

    $rootScope.$on('someObj:changed', (event, someObj, source) => {
        //Use Bracket notation to access the function
        self["_convertTo" + source](someObj)
    });
}
```

---

As per comment, except source, I would recommend you create a list of `sources`, then in the event handler get all method except source and execute them.

```
const MyFactory = function () {
    //Store the reference to a variable
    const self = this;
    const sources = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    $rootScope.$on('someObj:changed', (event, someObj, source) => {
        //Use Bracket notation to access the function
        var expectSource = sources.filter(x => x !== source);
        expectSource.forEach(x => self["_convertTo" + x](someObj))          
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But I need to call all converters **except** the source converter, so I would still need an array to hold all the converter function references right?

Comment: @lenny, See updated answer, I will prefer to save the reference of  `sources`